# CGI/Python Script - Number Cycling and Displaying Photos

Tags: python, cgi

I am working on a CGI script in Python where I have to display an image and a name. When you click next and/or previous, it brings up the next/previous pictures in the list.

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi

ls = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]

print "Content-type: text/html"
print 

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

number = data.getvalue("number", "0")
int_num = int(number)

item = ls[int_num]

print """
  <table border>
    <tr> <td colspan=2 align=center> <font size=+3 color=red> %s </font> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td align=center> <a href="/cgi-bin/09042013/lab2script1?number=%s">Previous</a>         </td>
     <td align=center> <a href="/cgi-bin/09042013/lab2script1?number=%s">Next</a> </td>
  </table>

""" % (number, int(number) - 1, int(number) + 1)

print "%s" % (item)
```

Here are my questions:
1.) How would I implement a feature where if it reached the end of the names list, it recycled back to the front, and vice-versa. I understand it would be a simple if statement, however all of my ideas result in a "server error".
2.) To display pictures with python, would I just use a list containing the image location just as I use ls (list of names)?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to rotate to the front or back of the list when the a limit is reached, you have to replace your code:

```
% (number, int(number) - 1, int(number) + 1)
```

by:

```
% (number, (int(number)-1)%n, (int(number)+1)%n)
```

where the operator "%" applied to numbers gives you the remainder of the division.
You should also add the line:

```
n=len(ls)
```

after the definition of ls.

Here, for instance when the upper boundary is reached the 5 is replaced by the remainder of the division of 5/5 which is 0, so this code gets the link to the figure of to the beginning of the list. When the the lower boundary is reached the idea is analogous.